# Cognos Expression Definition: How do I deal with apostrophies in a string?

Tags: cognos-10

I am attempting to improve an existing "data item query expression" in Cognos 10 via Report Studio.  The current expression works fine... except it can't accommodate words with an apostrophe in them.

In many cases, we have just removed the apostrophe in our supporting data sources, but instances of apostrophes remain. Example:  L'ESSENTIAL has been changed to L ESSENTIAL.  L'AGENDA has become L AGENDA.  My goal is to correct the expression so when it does encounter a L'ESSENTIAL or L'AGENDA it knows what to do with them.

The trial-and-error efforts generally result in parsing errors.

I've tried to surrounding or preceding the apostrophe with quotes"', asterisks *', tildes ~' and percents %' but none of these iterations have been successful.

Here is a highly abbreviated version of the formula:

case when [_Dimensions].[Product Dimension (Configured)].[Product Dimension (Configured)].[Item].[Catalog Brand or Catalog Group] in ('L ESSENTIEL','L AGENDA') then '01 NO APOSTROPHE'
       when [_Dimensions].[Product Dimension (Configured)].[Product Dimension (Configured)].[Item].[Catalog Brand or Catalog Group] in **('L%'ESSENTIEL','L%'AGENDA')** then '02 WITH APOSTROPHE'
else '99 EVERYTHING ELSE'
end

**How do I re-write the bolded part so it recognizes L'ESSENTIAL and L'AGENDA as strings?**

Forgive my lack of experience in this arena... this is not my area of expertise, unfortunately.

Thanks in advance for any novice level guidance you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape single-quote characters by using two single-quotes in a row. So the in() clause in bold above would be:

```
in ('L''ESSENTIEL','L''AGENDA')
```